# saving private RSA key

Tags: security, kotlin, rsa, keystore, private-key

I have a messaging app, in order to secure the users messages i first encrypt the message with an AES key then i encrypt that AES key with the other user's known public RSA key and send the AES key with the message.
when the key arrives at the other user he decrypts that key with a private RSA key saved on the phones database.
I've learned when trying to upload the app to google play that this is an unsafe way of storing the the private RSA key.
I've tried storing the key pair in a KeyStore but when i try decrypting the AES key with the private i cant access the private key's encoded byte Array that's because i saved KeyStore doesn't give  allow accesses to it.
are there any ways of solving this?

Creating and saving the keys:

```
fun generateRSAKey(context: Context): KeyPair {
        val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
            AppConst.RSA, "AndroidKeyStore"
        )
        val spec:AlgorithmParameterSpec
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
             spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    "privateKey",
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
                )
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setKeySize(1024)
                .build()
        }
        else
        {
            val start: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val end: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100)
             spec = KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias("privateKey")
                .setSubject(X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                .setStartDate(start.time)
                .setEndDate(end.time)
                .build()
        }
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec)
        return  keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

    }
```

Retrieving the keys:

```
val keyStore=EncryptionUtil.getKeyStoreInstance()
            keyStore.load(null)
            val entry: KeyStore.Entry = keyStore.getEntry("privateKey", null)
            val privateKey: PrivateKey = (entry as KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry).privateKey
            val decryptedAES = EncryptionUtil.decryptRSA(
                android.util.Base64.decode(
                    aesKey,
                    android.util.Base64.DEFAULT
                ), KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey.encoded))
            )
```

Comment: If you want to decrypt an AES key you'll need to create the RSA key with `PURPOSE_DECRYPT`. Key wrap is slightly easier to use in my opinion, in which case you need `PURPOSE_KEYWRAP`.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveanPolk so i should change KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN to PURPOSE_DECRYPT?